# Find css class on div and get values

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find a class on a div (where the value will always end in `0bg`), given a partial string, and then get its background style value.

For example:

```
.xx-color-100bg{
    background-color: #323334;
}
```

```
<div class="heading xx-color-100bg"></div>
```

```
document.querySelectorAll(".heading").classList.contains("0bg").style.background
```

The solution above errors with `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'contains')`

How can I find the necessary class and grab it's background-color value?

Comment: `querySelectorAll()` returns a NodeList.  `classList` is undefined on NodeList (it is found on a DOMElement

Comment: I wonder if this is good enough: `.querySelectorAll('[class$="0bg"]')`

Comment: You can include the 0bg in your querySelector, `".heading[class$='0bg']"`

Answer (score 1):

`querySelectorAll()` returns a `NodeList`, so you can't use `classList`. You need to loop over the DOMElements in the list or just assume the first one is what you need:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".heading").forEach(e => {
    // do something with e.classList
});

// OR

document.querySelectorAll(".heading")[0].classList // the first element
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the solution right after posting the question:

```
window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector(".heading[class*='0bg'")).backgroundColor;
```